# How do I find the highest allowable combination of variables?

Tags: c#

I'm a novice programmer and looking for advice on what the best algorithm is to solve my transport problem.

So I have 12 variables (which are increasing with time). I want to choose the highest allowable combination of variables at that moment in time. I have a 12x12 boolean matrix of unique combinations which are allowed.

For example, 
Variable 1 (V1) = 10 seconds, V2 = 20 secs, V3 = 12 secs, etc... however V1 cannot be combined with V3 or V7. V2 cannot be combined with V4, V7 or V10... etc.

What algorithm should I use to choose the highest allowable combination of variables at any moment in time?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: How many items are you allowed to combine at once? You talk about pairs, so does that mean you must only combine two at once? (Obviously there must be a limit otherwise you could just combine all the combinable ones! :)

Comment: It sounds like you should have one variable that represents a collection of some sort, rather than a variable number of variables.  Also, which language is this in; you've tagged it C# and phython.  Which are you using?

Comment: Each variable is different. Some of them can be combined with only 2 other variables, and some of them can be combined with 10 other variables. Are you suggesting that I should just calculate every allowable combination?

Comment: @Servy, I tagged C# and python because I know how to write basic code in both

Comment: @AndyH That didn't answer my question.  Which language are you using right now for this problem.  It's relevant.  You shouldn't just go around tagging a bunch of unrelated language that you aren't using in your question just because you know them.

Comment: @Servy Sorry about that, I'll not do that in the future. I'm using C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a straight-forward loop -> max situation.
Simply loop over every single combination - perform whatever operation you need (v1 + v2) - and if it's higher than max - set it as max.

maxing some assumptions about structure:

```
var combinations = new bool[12,12];
var values = new int[12];

var max = 0;
var maxX = -1;
var maxY = -1;

//Loop across all combinations
for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 12; y++)
    {
        if(combinations[x,y]) //Check if it's a valid combination
        {
            if(values[x] + values[y] > max)
            {
                max = values[x] + values[y];
                maxX = x;
                maxY = y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Something like this may work, for arbitrary subsets:

```
var combinations = new bool[12,12];
var values = new int[12];

var max = 0;

//Get all the other variables this variable can be combined with
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    var validCombinations = new List<int>(){ i };

    for (int k = 0; k < 12; k++)
    {
        if(combinations[i,k])
        {
            validCombinations.Add(k);
        }
    }

    //get the actual values for the variables, and sum them:
    var sum = validCombinations.Select(variable => values[variable]).Sum();

    if(sum > max)
    {
        max = sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: This only lets me add two variables together. How would I do this if the first variable is allowed to be combined with all of the other variables?

Comment: @AndyH So if the first can be combined with the second, and the second can be combined with the third, but the first cannot be combined with the third, then what?  Your question implies specifically pairs, not arbitrarily sized subsets.  How does your 12x12 matrix determine what subsets are valid?

Comment: I've had another go :)